# How to install openGauss on a Python 3.7 environment

Tags: open-gauss

when I install openGauss on a python3.7 environment, it reminds me the python version is not support, so how can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Following this step

1. open the `gspylib/common/CheckPythonVersion.py` file
2. change `if not pythonVersion = (3, 6):` to `if not pythonVersion > = (3, 6):`
3. type the "ESC" key to enter the instruction mode, execute: wq save and exit the modification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install openGauss on a Python 3.7 environment, you will need to downgrade your Python version to a supported version. You can find instructions on how to downgrade your Python version on the OpenGauss website. Additionally, you may need to install additional packages or libraries to ensure that openGauss is compatible with your Python version.